# Error creating executable in electron

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, angular-cli, electron-packager

I'm developing an app with electron and angular cli [2](http://www.blog.bdauria.com/?p=806)

The problem is when I install other node packages.

In development mode works fine, but when exporting the final application with electron-packager it tells me that:

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
    Uncaught Exception:
    Error: Can not find module 'name_package'
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Some node packages are:
`jsonfile`,
`async`,
`electron-json-storage`

How can I include all node packages in the final application?

Comment: Use 'Rollup' https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

Comment: But that is for angular 2 and not for angular cli, the environments are configured differently

In fact it is added with the parameter --aot al building and it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Set the [prune](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md#prune) option of electron-packager to false like this:

```
electron-packager . "myApp" --prune=false
```

When prune is true electron-packager will remove all packages in the devDependencies so setting it to false will probably solve your problem.